# Question about the gradient of a function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, maxima-minima

We consider a function of class $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, by searching a max or min between the points of $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \;\; | \;\; x^2+y^2=1\}$, if $(x_0,y_0)$ is one of them, is it true that there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=2\lambda (x_0,y_0)?$ Why?

Comment: Maximum or minimum of what ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Then $S=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^1\mid g(x,y)=1\}$ and the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) tells us that if $f$ has a local extreme at some point $(x_0,y_0)\in S$, then $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=\lambda\nabla g(x_0,y_0)$, for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. And $\nabla g(x_0,y_0)=(2x_0,2y_0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the extremum of some $f(x,y)$, we can parameterize the locus as $x=\cos t,y=\sin t$.

Then by the chain rule, the stationary points of $f$ are given by

$$\frac{df}{dt}=\nabla f\cdot(-\sin t,\cos t)=0$$ and these are such that $$\nabla f=\lambda(\cos t,\sin t).$$

In other words, the derivative of the function when you remain in the locus is zero when the gradient is normal to the locus, i.e. parallel to a normal to the locus.

This is a quite general property.

Comment: Thank you very much.